# How do I automatically sort a has_many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems like a really simple question but I haven't seen it answered anywhere.

In rails if you have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments 
end 
class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :article 
end
```

Why can't you order the comments with something like this:

```
@article.comments(:order=>"created_at DESC")
```

Named scope works if you need to reference it a lot and even people do stuff like this:

```
@article.comments.sort { |x,y| x.created_at <=> y.created_at }
```

But something tells me it should be simpler.  What am I missing?

Comment: Be careful, you are using an unexpected method: @article.comments(reload = false) is for forcing a cache-miss (to force the reload of a relation). If you provide a hash, it's the same as @article.comments(true). Don't forget to use .all(:order => '...'). Broke my leg a few times already.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can specify the sort order for the bare collection with an option on `has_many` itself:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments, :order => 'created_at DESC'
end 
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :article 
end
```

Or, if you want a simple, non-database method of sorting, use [sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003151):

```
article.comments.sort_by &:created_at
```

Collecting this with the ActiveRecord-added methods of ordering:

```
article.comments.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')
article.comments.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')
```

Your mileage may vary: the performance characteristics of the above solutions will change wildly depending on how you're fetching data in the first place and which Ruby you're using to run your app.

Comment: Thanks, the "all" is probably the simplest.  Good stuff!

Comment: in Rails 4, the order option has been removed.  Use a lambda `-> { order(created_at: :desc) }` instead.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-model-with-order

Comment: this was deprecated with rails 4, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order

Answer (score 61):

As of Rails 4, you would do:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end 
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :article 
end
```

For a `has_many :through` relationship the argument order matters (it has to be second):

```
class Article
  has_many :comments, -> { order('postables.sort' :desc) }, 
           :through => :postable
end
```

If you will always want to access comments in the same order no matter the context you could also do this via `default_scope` within `Comment` like:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :article 
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

However this can be problematic for the [reasons discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087336/why-is-using-the-rails-default-scope-often-recommend-against).

Before Rails 4 you could specify `order` as a key on the relationship, like:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments, :order => 'created_at DESC'
end
```

As Jim mentioned you can also use `sort_by` after you have fetched results although in any result sets of size this will be significantly slower (and use a lot more memory) than doing your ordering through SQL/ActiveRecord.

If you are doing something where adding a default order is cumbersome for some reason or you want to override your default in certain cases, it is trivial to specify it in the fetching action itself:

```
sorted = article.comments.order('created_at').all
```

Comment: Where can I specify it in the fetching action itself? Do I override a method in the model?

Comment: @Wit - you can add `.order()` to the method chain, like in the last example. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I am sorry. I can't remember what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: The has_many, through polymorphic example is super helpful here!

Comment: Warning: if you do the lambda in rails 6, yo lose the implicit inverse_of, so if you try to save the record with a new record in a has_many, it will not autosave the child first like it will if you don't have the lambda.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Rails 2.3 and want to use the same default ordering for all collections of this object you can use default_scope to order your collection.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :class

  default_scope :order => 'name'

end
```

Then if you call

```
@students = @class.students
```

They will be ordered as per your default_scope. TBH in a very general sense ordering is the only really good use of default scopes.

Comment: As of Rails 4 this is not compliant. See this solution for correct Rails 4 syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506038/rails-4-default-scope

Answer (score 6):

You can use ActiveRecord's find method to get your objects and sort them too.

```
  @article.comments.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC")
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Or the shorthand method @article.comments.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')

Answer (score 3):

And if you need to pass some additional arguments like `dependent: :destroy` or whatever, you should append the ones after a lambda, like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, dependent: :destroy
end
```