# Rails 4 default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, default-scope

In my Rails app have a default scope that looks like this:

```
default_scope order: 'external_updated_at DESC'
```

I have now upgraded to Rails 4 and, of course, I get the following deprecation warning "Calling #scope or #default_scope with a hash is deprecated. Please use a lambda containing a scope.". I have successfully converted my other scopes but I don't know what the syntax for default_scope should be. This doesn't work:

```
default_scope, -> { order: 'external_updated_at' }
```

Comment: Related: should default_scope be [avoided altogether](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13965#issuecomment-34407465), and what are some alternative approaches?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Should be only:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { order(:external_updated_at) } 
end
```

default_scope accept a block, lambda is necessary for scope(), because there are 2 parameters, name and block:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Luke. I got a syntax error, then I changed it to default_scope { order('external_updated_at') } and it worked. Can you edit your answer, please, so I can accpet it?

Comment: This didn't work for me in 4.0.2 without the arrow. My working solution was ```default_scope -> { order_by(:created_at => :desc) }```

Comment: By convention, symbols are preferred when referencing attributes. `default_scope { order(:external_updated_at) }`

Comment: BTW The correct answer to @JoeGatt question is `default_scope order('external_updated_at DESC')`

Comment: This does not address ordering if you have results that have varied case (upcase vs. downcase)... any thoughts on ordering via default_scope while forcing downcase?

Answer (score 21):

This is what worked for me:

```
default_scope  { order(:created_at => :desc) }
```

Comment: In new Ruby syntax: `default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }`

Answer (score 7):

This also worked for me:

`default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }`

Answer (score 2):

This worked from me (just for illustration with a where) because I came to this topic via the same problem.

```
default_scope { where(form: "WorkExperience") }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `lambda` keyword. This is useful for multiline blocks.

```
default_scope lambda {
  order(external_updated_at: :desc)
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
default_scope -> { order(external_updated_at: :desc) }
```

and

```
default_scope { order(external_updated_at: :desc) }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Rails 4

```
default_scope { order(external_updated_at: :desc) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

Don't forget the `->` symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
default_scope { 
      where(published: true) 
}
```

Try This.