# How do I automatically sort a has_many relationship in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738971/how-do-i-automatically-sort-a-has-many-relationship-in-rails), but it's very outdated (2009).

I would like to know how to sort the collection on a has_many relationship, preferably in the model.

Something like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments, :order => 'created_at DESC'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments, -> { order "created_at DESC" } 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntax changes when you migrated to Rails 4 version.
Check this:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many