# Set default order of a has_many resource at the Active Record level

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you set the default order of resources coming out of the db.
Something like:

```
has_many :trips, :order => 'departure_date DESC'
```

There is some business logic that needs the most recent date being checked first.

Current code results in this error.

```
ArgumentError (Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name,     :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type):
```

Was trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738971/how-do-i-automatically-sort-a-has-many-relationship-in-rails) as it received good reviews (6yrs ago.) Am I missing something simple or has that be depricated in favor of a better way today?

Comment: Which version of rails you are using?

Comment: @Pavan Rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
has_many :trips, -> { order(departure_date: :desc) }
```

[Scroll down to "scopes"](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)

Comment: I've not used the ` -> ` before. Can you explain what it is doing?

Comment: Added documentation link!